# Why needn't the object add @Parcelize when I try to store state?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Compose by the [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

The article tell me:

*All data types that are added to the Bundle are saved automatically. The simplest solution is to add the @Parcelize annotation to the object.*

And it gives me the sample code.

```
@Parcelize
data class City(val name: String, val country: String) : Parcelable

@Composable
fun CityScreen() {
    var selectedCity = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(City("Madrid", "Spain"))
    }
}
```

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs).

I find the `data class Post` doesn't add `@Parcelize`, and `val featured = remember { PostRepo.getFeaturedPost() }` is OK, why?

```
@Composable
fun Home() {
    val featured = remember { PostRepo.getFeaturedPost() }
    val posts = remember { PostRepo.getPosts() }
    ...
}


object PostRepo {
    fun getPosts(): List<Post> = posts
    fun getFeaturedPost(): Post = posts.random()
}


@Immutable
data class Post(
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val subtitle: String? = null,
    val url: String,
    val metadata: Metadata,
    @DrawableRes val imageId: Int,
    @DrawableRes val imageThumbId: Int,
    val tags: Set<String>
)

@Immutable
data class Metadata(
    val author: PostAuthor,
    val date: String,
    val readTimeMinutes: Int
)

@Immutable
data class PostAuthor(
    val name: String,
    val url: String? = null
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `remember` helps you retain state across recompositions, the state is not retained across configuration changes. For this, you  use `rememberSaveable`. `RememberSaveable` automatically saves any value that can be saved in a `Bundle`. For other values, you can pass in a custom saver object.

Since `RememberSaveable` automatically saves any value that can be saved in a Bundle , it requires the class to be `Parcelable` unlike remember .